# Which processor should I use to combine different JSON inputs into one object?

Tags: apache-nifi

[image]

I'd like to set up a dataflow that takes in multiple JSON inputs, and combines them into a single JSON object with multiple properties (I'm currently using a few GenerateFlowFile processors to generate the inputs), and send the data every 10 seconds via the PublishMQTT processor.

The inputs come in at different intervals (1-5seconds), and examples are:

- **{"temperature": 60}**
- **{"pressure": 30}**

I would like to compile the incoming data into one object i.e. **{"temperature": 60,"pressure": 30}** before sending it to the PublishMQTT processor.

Also, if fresh data with the same attribute comes in before the message is sent, it should update the attribute in the same object instead of being queued. i.e. If new data entered **{"pressure": 150}**, the output object should be updated to **{"temperature": 60,"pressure": 150}** before it is sent out via MQTT

I'm guessing that I will require a processor (see blue circle in attached image), but I'm not sure what processor(s) does what I've described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a provided processor that can do this because it requires some knowledge of your data. You would have to implement a custom processor, or use ExecuteScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wait-notify to get flowfiles wait for another like in this example:

https://pierrevillard.com/2018/06/27/nifi-workflow-monitoring-wait-notify-pattern-with-split-and-merge/comment-page-1/

Note that the link is only an example, your use case is different and must be changed according to your requirements.

Then you can merge the information in one flowfile and use [EL](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) to generate the new json value.